# String to Date or Date and Time

Tags: php, date, time

I have a string like this "20180720171534449" which is a kind of time stamp, is there an easy way I can convert this using PHP and format it as a date or date and time that makes sense to a human?

TIA

Peter

Answer (score 1):

You have an 'YmdHisv' format where v is miliseconds.
Miliseconds is not parsable (as I found out today) with date_create_from_format so you need to remove that first from the string with substr.

```
$s = "20180720171534449";
$date = date_create_from_format('YmdHis', substr($s,0,-3));
echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d H:i:s'); //2018-07-20 17:15:34
```

https://3v4l.org/m1XNd

---

As Ghost pointed out milliseconds is parasble if using microseconds `u` instead.

```
$s = "20180720171534449";
$date = date_create_from_format('YmdHisu', $s);
echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d H:i:s\.v'); //2018-07-20 17:15:34.449
```

Comment: no need to make string operations, since microseconds can take 2 up to 6 digits https://3v4l.org/VW8sh

Comment: Didn't know about the `u` I thought it was `v`. Thanks!

Comment: Thankyou, that worked great! :-)

Comment: @Peter No problem. I see that you are new here, take the tour and learn some of the basics of SO https://stackoverflow.com/tour and you will ern a badge when you have read the full page.